# Magento Database Import Error

Tags: php, database, magento

I want to import my local magento database into live one but I get this error on phpmyadmin:

```
Error

SQL query: Documentation

--
-- Database: `round_gain`
--
DELIMITER $$--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetCart` ( IN deleteBefore datetime, IN storeId smallint ) BEGIN DELETE FROM mventory_cart_item WHERE date_time < deleteBefore;

SELECT *
FROM mventory_cart_item
WHERE store_id = storeId
ORDER BY date_time DESC ;

END$$

MySQL said: Documentation
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: try removing the `definer`=`root`@`localhost` from the definition

Comment: @RamRaider can you explain it by detailes pleas?
i'm not familiar with database stuffs.

Comment: The StoredProcedure is trying to impersonate the root user - it is doubtful that your live host would allow you to be the root user.  So, try replacing the "definer=root@localhost" with the username you have been assigned - ie "definer=`shhs_1234`@`localhost`" or, as I have found with my host - remove it entirely from the sql definition for the stored procedure and then run that sql in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Login in phpmyadmin with user which have all previleges then import database. this error seems that you are not logged in with all previleges.